# United Kingdom's three-name-cities; is there a generic way to write them?

Tags: etymology, demonyms, toponyms

There are city names in the United Kingdom like "Stratford-upon-Avon" or "Newcastle upon Tyne". Then, I wonder: is there any general rule on how they should be written?

`Case`: In general, I see the second name is written in lowercase.

`Dash`:  However, I wonder if a dash should or should not be written in between each pair of words.

Hence, what is more appropriate, if there is any standard?

- Name1-name2-Name3
- Name1 name2 Name3

More names I came across:

- Stoke-on-Trent
- Oldbury-on-Severn
- Wotton-under-Edge
- Wells-next-the-Sea
- Sutton-cum-Lound
- Southend-on-Sea
- Newbiggin-by-the-Sea
- Newport-On-Tay

in [Geonames](http://geonames.org/) I could find more than a hundred.

Comment: To complicate matters: the city of Stoke-on-Trent was created from the amalgamation of six towns (that still exist) one of which is Stoke-*upon*-Trent.

Comment: Doesn't 'There are city names in the United Kingdom like "Stratford-upon-Avon" or "Newcastle upon Tyne"'  render 'I wonder: is there any general rule on how they should be written?'  needless?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There isn't a standard. You just have to memorize them. :) On the one hand, you have:

- Stratford-upon-Avon
- Stoke-on-Trent

On the other, you have:

- Kingston upon Hull
- Newcastle upon Tyne

In the cases of lesser-known towns, the dashed approach seems to be used far more commonly when the town's name features a preposition, such as the examples below. This practice generally does not carry over town names of three words or more that do not contain prepositions, such as *Welwyn Garden City* and *Portishead and North Weston*.

- Appleby-in-Westmorland
- Barrow-in-Ferness
- Henley-in-Arden
- Kirton-in-Lindsey
- Burnham-on-Crouch
- Chapel-en-le-Frith
- Stockton-on-Tees

There are, however, occasional exceptions, such as:

- Medlar with Wesham
- Northleach with Eastington
- Burton upon Trent

You'll even find one or two towns that seem to disobey all statutes of sense, like Burnham-on-Sea and Highbridge (that's a single town). I can't speak to why the dash is used, except in that it might help people read multi-word town names cohesively (but really, Stratford-upon-Avon literally *is* Stratford *upon* Avon). It does seem the majority of towns use the dash, but there are several examples of towns and cities that omit it. As such, my advice is to check external references before assuming.

Comment: This list doesn't include fictional towns. E.g., Doctor Dolittle came from Puddleby-on-the-Marsh. I'll bet there are many more such towns in literature. Does this not count because it's 4 words?

Comment: Newcastle-under-Lyme is the reason why the other Newcastle retains its epithet. (Unhelpfully, Newcastle under Lyme College apparently does not have hyphens). And there are many other multiword towns.

Comment: @Barmar Of course I'm not including fictional towns... :) Generally, the point is that there is no standard, so in the case of fictional towns, one should refer to the work of fiction to which the town belongs.

Comment: @TimLymington Hence the "as far as I know". I don't doubt that there are more, but my answer was meant more to illustrate that there is no standard rule. The Britons are a race shy to standards, you see. :)

Comment: Don't forget *Ashton-under-Lyne* and *Lee-on-the-Solent*, often called  *Lee-on-Solent*. If you don't insist on prepositions, there's also *Chester-le-Street*.

Comment: There are also a few of these in the U.S., like *Croton-on-Hudson*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, note there are more than a hundred. Just updated my question with some more.

Comment: @fedorqui The answer is: "There is no general rule, refer to an authority on a case-by-case basis." Stack Exchange doesn't allow answers that list every possible known variant. Such a question would be off topic and closed.

Comment: @Hugo thanks, it makes sense. Then, the answer to my question is just "no, there is no standard", which is what R Mac wrote. I will accept it in a while, although I think the sentence "Fortunately, there are only four such cities..." would be better removed, because unfortunately is not true :(

Comment: I removed it. I made that statement under the impression we are talking about _cities_. If we're talking about any towns of any kind (including fictional ones), it is indeed quite wrong.

Comment: I also edited my response to elaborate on the use of dashes in town names. My original response stands: always check, as neither practice is used consistently. However, when it comes to smaller towns, the dash is used much more commonly than it is omitted.

Comment: This ended up being a beautiful answer! Thanks a lot for the effort and the capacity to write such a comprehensive text.

Comment: Just to add, since it isn’t stated outright in the answer: what the question calls ‘the second name’ is always, in this type of name, some kind of preposition and/or article. As surmised in the question, these are always lowercase, in accordance with how such words are normally written in names and titles (Shakespeare’s _The Taming of the Shrew_ usually has lowercase _of_ and _the_ as well, for example).